# How do I fund a project?

Tags: community-official-site

I'm just trying to find out how to fund a Drupal project.

I found https://www.drupalfund.us/, but it seems it is not really working because there are no active projects, or maybe I'm missing something.

At this moment, how could I fund a Drupal project?

Comment: Hey, you, the downvoter, can you help to improve the question please?

Comment: I just read this interesting article: http://www.jrockowitz.com/blog/crowdfunding?utm_source=drupal-newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=drupal-newsletter-20170615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is not an obvious task to get completed.

The most recent, fairly successful, funding campaign that I'm aware of is for upgrading the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to D8, via `#d8rules`. For some pointers about it, start from the [community promotion ad](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3616/39516) (disclosure: I posted it) which looks like so:

[image: If you want Rules for D8, then checkout and/or support #d8rules]

Depending on what the subject of your project is, maybe your project also fits [the criteria for starting a similar ad](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3606/39516) ... free of charge (just a relevant image and URL will get you going)!

Answer (score 2):

If your project uses company's X API or library, you can try approaching company X about funding your project. As it would be beneficial for them if people don't have to invent the wheel in order to use their service.

Comment: Good point, and a variation of "API" could be "3rd party library", no? If so, I think you should integrate that in your answer also (no credits due ...)